# Comparing conversion rate in A/B testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a website, and I want to see if offering a 5% or a 10% discount in an advertisement increases the click-through rate. Essentially an A/B test but with 2 alternatives, so an A/B/C test.

In the end I want to be able to say something like:

```
"5% discount improved the click-through rate by 7% compared to no discount". 
"10% discount improved the click-through rate by 8% compared to no discount".
```

I guesstimate the click-through rate will go up by a maximum of +20%.

What I want to do in the current stage is figure out which test/confidence intervals I should be using and then conduct a proper power analysis.

Should I be using just confidence intervals (my random variables follow Binomial distribution)? Or should I be doing test of proportions.

e.g.

`H0: 1.1 * Conversation rate under A = Conversation rate under B
HA: 1.1 * Conversation rate under A < Conversation rate under B
And if p-value > alpha then I reject H0 in favour of HA and conclude that B design converts 10% more users.`

Since I have A/B and A/C I will also take into account Bonferroni correction for the alpha. Since I want an alpha = 0.05 then each hypothesis should be tested at alpha=0.025.

Please correct me if I am wrong, thanks.

Comment: Perform a logistic regression.  You can compare the interventions directly to the "no discount" option.  Also, a 20% change in clickthrough (e.g. from 20% clicktrhough to 40% clickthrough) is a very large change.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I am not sure how I am supposed to use a logistic regression. Can you expand on that? Also I am not sure how I can get a significance level from looking into the co-efficients of logistic regression, or how to estimate the number of users to include in each group. Ideally I would involve as few as necessary in groups B and C, so I want to do a power analysis now and detect changes (significantly) as small as 0.5%. So from 20~>20.1%.

By 20% I meant conversion rate from 20% ~> 24%. For example lets say I have N=100.000.

Comment: A) Most statistical packages like SPSS, R, or SAS will have logistic regression functionality.  This isn't something you'd do in something like Excel.  Plenty of free tools.  B) The output of these languages will include hypothesis tests on the coefficients.  C) Imbalanced groups will lead to poorer power, but I think you can do one now given your hypothesized effect sizes.  This sounds like a lot of work for someone on CV to do for free.  Have you considered hiring someone to help you with this?